# Update Azure Staging deployment will create new url

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, windows-server-2008, azure-storage

I am using cloud service for my web application currently it is in development phase. My all updated code is on staging environment, I have create staging server on May 13, 2012. Now from last two days my data is rolled back to May 13, 2013 means my server either restart or upgraded. I am using Visual Studio 2010 publish tool to upload my data.
I want to know how can I upload my latest code so on roll back latest code remains on new server instance. Also I don't want to regenerate my staging url because we are using this in our other services so its not possible to change that url frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem in your approot is non-persistent. Dynamically created files being deleted on   rollback, update or duplication of a roleinstance.

Do you use Web Deploy to publish your changes? If so, your approot is just dynamically changed and changes get cleared on rollback.

If you do not want to lose your development-progress, you have to create a new package and update your whole role-instance.

"Also I don't want to regenerate my staging url"
What do you mean with that? If you create a cloudservice you get a unique url for your staging enviroment, that does not change as long as you dont delete your enviroment!?

Comment: Yes we are using web deploy to publish our changes, Can you suggest me what is best practice to update pakage, directly from my system drive or from storage account?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out for myself, what best practice is.

For packaging your application you could use the Azure SDK Commandline Tool CSPack http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433055.aspx and upload it via Windows Azure Web GUI